# Debian system simply ignoring the POSIX Regex Expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, posix

Not able to match the below expressions inside i386/debian:stable docker container.

```
[:alnum:]   [:cntrl:]   [:lower:]   [:space:]
[:alpha:]   [:digit:]   [:print:]   [:upper:]
[:blank:]   [:graph:]   [:punct:]   [:xdigit:]
```

Example code which I want to run is:

```
ss -plant | awk -v pattern="$apacheBinName" -v pattern2="LISTEN" '{if($0 ~ pattern && $0 ~ pattern2) {print $4};}' | awk -v pattern3='*' 'BEGIN { FS=":" } {
        if ($(NF-1) ~ /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/)
            print $(NF-1)":"$NF;
        if ($(NF-1) ~ pattern3) print $NF
    }'
```

Comment: Why do you need `/[[:space:]]{0,}Listen[[:space:]]{1,}/` regex? Your `awk` will work without that.

Comment: @anubhava How? Please tell me, I need to know this. And the second thing is, I will need this kind of pattern matching on later stages. So, I need a permanent solution for this.

Comment: debian ships `mawk` by default, I'm not sure it fully supports posix regex

Comment: @anubhava In my actual scenario I have a *.config file in place of 'echo "  Listen 80"'.

Comment: Doesn't really matter then command would be: `awk '$1 == "Listen" {print $2}' fioe.config`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for pointing this out. I'm new to shell script and awk. I'm going to change my existing logic now. But do you have any solution to the problem -- How to use these POSIX regex in this debian container?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi It is not about awk, even grep is failing. I'm not able to grep for patterns like '[[:alnum:]]{0,5}'. Please comment if you have any solution.